# Does my ASP.NET cache store on server or browser

Tags: asp.net, html, caching, web

in ASP.NET, If I use:

```
$<%@OutputCache Duration="3" VaryByParam="*" %>
```

or

```
Cache.Insert("Names", mydataset);
```

Does this store the cache on the browser or the server? I know they're two different methods for caching and there are probably several more but I'm trying to find out when the cache is stored on the client browser or on the server and where can I find the pros and cons between cache being store on either of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
<%@OutputCache Duration="3" VaryByParam="*" %>
```

May be cached at both, the server or the client because by default the `Location` value of the `OutputCache` directive is `Any`. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for reference.

Now, this:

```
Cache.Insert("Names", mydataset);
```

Will be cached on the server side in the application Cache.

Comment: @lcarus does "may be cached at both" mean I have a choice and this is specified by an additional parameter?

Comment: @mjroodt Yes, you can, that's what the `Location` attribute is used for. See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is stored on the server. Output cache stores the html output obtained after the page is processed, so that the server need not process the page over and over again unnecessarily.

Read More: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020113508/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022802-1.aspx

Comment: -1 Not entirely true. The OutputCache directive as it stands on the question, may cache the page on the client too. See the link on my answer and this other one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation(v=vs.100).aspx